# Push Notifications Not Working Properly (push.js) | .Net Core SignalR

Tags: push-notification, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using SignalR in .net Core application for Push Notifications. Quartz running properly but I am getting this js error "Uncaught (in promise) Permission request declined" in console. 
How to resolve this?

Here is my code that is running on local perfectly.

```
function PushNotification(title, bodyText, countryid, SportName, CountryName, ContestGroupName, HomeTeamName, AwayTeamName, MatchId) {
    Push.create(title, {
        body: bodyText,
        icon: {
            x32: '/images/countries/countries-small/' + countryid + '.jpg'
        },
        timeout: 15000,
        onClick: function () {
            window.focus();
            var url = "";
            var myJson = $.ajax({
                url: '/Matches/NotificationsMatchDetailLink',
                data: { sportName: SportName, countryName: CountryName, contestGroupName: ContestGroupName, homeTeamName: HomeTeamName, awayTeamName: AwayTeamName, matchId: MatchId },
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json'
            }).responseJSON;
            window.location.href = myJson;
            this.close();
        },
        vibrate: [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200]
    });
}
```